# Splitting cameracontrol sample OpenCv4Android in two threads

Tags: android, multithreading, opencv, android-camera

I have imported into Eclipse Juno the sample of OpenCv4Android, ver. 2.4.5, called "cameracontrol". It can be found here:[Camera Control OpenCv4Android Sample](https://github.com/nehiljain/opencv4android/tree/master/samples/tutorial-5-cameracontrol).

Now I want to use this project as base for mine. I want to process every frame with image-processing techniques, so, in order to improve performance, I want to split the main activity of the project in two classes: one that is merely the activity and one (a thread) that is responsible for preview.

How can I do? Are there any examples about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be a complete answer as I'm only learning about this myself at the moment, but I'll provide as much info as I can.

You will likely have to grab the images from the camera yourself and dispatch it to threads. This is because your activity in the example gets called with a frame from the camera and has to return the frame to be displayed (immediately) as the return value. You can't get 2+ frames to process in parallel without showing a blank screen in the meantime or some other hacky stuff. You'll probably want to allocate a (fixed sized) buffer somewhere, then start processing a frame with a worker thread when you get one (this would be the dispatcher). Once your worker thread is done he notifies the dispatcher who gives the image to the view. If frames come from the camera while all worker threads are busy (i.e. there are no free slots in the buffer), the frame is dropped. Once a space in the buffer frees up again, the next frame is accepted and processed.

You can look at the code of the `initialitzeCamera` function of `JavaCameraView` and `NativeCameraView` to get an idea of how to do this (also google should help, as  this is how apps without OpenCV have to do it as well). For me the native camera performs significantly better though (even without heavy processing it's just much smoother), but ymmv...

I can't help with actual details about the implementation since I'm not that far into it myself yet. I dope this provides some ideas though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, my target is to capture frames, to save them into a buffer with a worker thread, and in background there should be another running thread that take a frame from the buffer, in order to process it with image-processing techniques. You've been very clear, thanks!